# is there onload event for the angular $uibModal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-directive

is there an event for angular $uibModal like onload to show a loader before the modal gets shown or loaded specially if the modal takes time to get loaded.

**Explain**

I need to show a loader for the user while waiting the modal file gets download from the server.

Comment: looks like yes, [Official docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs#return) mention `rendered` promise

Comment: @Yanis-git I need it befor it fetches the files and download them from the server.

Comment: in my opinion, juste before to call the code who ask to open your modal, you display your loaded, then when `rendered` promise is resolve, you hide it.